# Identifying and writing the font size

Tags: fontsize, expansion

I am trying to identify whether the current font size is `small`.
So here is a MWE of what I am trying to do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\f@size = 9}{the size is 9}{the size is not 9}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\small
\ifthenelse{\f@size = 9}{the size is 9}{the size is not 9}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\f@size = {\small \f@size} }{the size is small}{the size is not small}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Well my desired output would be something like

[image: output of the font size]

but somehow `{\small \f@size}` is not "expanded" as a number, which actually is. Thanks for help. :)

Comment: Just to print out the font size name?

Comment: It might be, but no :D. I just want to adapt my text depending on the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind? The `\definesizecommand` macro is able to define a command that behaves differently in the various sizes. This command can also have arguments, as shown by `\baz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% relsize builds a list \rs@fontsizes of the form
%   \rs@size\normalfont{10.0pt}\rs@size\small{9.0pt}...
% and we can use it for building a different list

\prop_new:N \g_lbj_size_to_name_prop
\prop_new:N \g_lbj_name_to_size_prop
\group_begin:
\cs_set:cpn { rs@size } #1 #2
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_lbj_size_to_name_prop { #2 } { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
 }
\use:c { rs@fontsizes }
% this is not used, but could become handy
\cs_set:cpn { rs@size } #1 #2
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_lbj_name_to_size_prop { \cs_to_str:N #1 } { #2 }
 }
\use:c { rs@fontsizes }
\group_end:

% just print the current size name
\NewDocumentCommand{\currentsizename}{}
 {
  \prop_item:Nf \g_lbj_size_to_name_prop { \dim_eval:n { \use:c {f@size} pt } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nf }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definesizecommand}{mmmO{}}
 {% #1 is the command to define,
  % #2 is the argument specifier,
  % #3 is the list of actions,
  % #4 is the optional action to do in uncovered cases
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}
   {
    \str_case:xnF
     { \prop_item:Nf \g_lbj_size_to_name_prop { \dim_eval:n { \use:c { f@size } pt } } }
     { #3 }
     { #4 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { x }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definesizecommand{\foo}{}{
  {normalsize}{normalfoo}
  {small}{smallfoo}
  {tiny}{tinyfoo}
}[extrafoo]

\definesizecommand{\baz}{m}{
  {normalsize}{---#1---}
  {small}{!#1!}
  {tiny}{?#1?}
}[(#1)]

\begin{document}

Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{x}

\small
Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{y}

\tiny
Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{z}

\Large
Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different version without loading `relsize`, but exploiting `\@currsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \lbj_curr_size:
 {
  \__lbj_curr_size:c { @currsize }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__lbj_curr_size:N
 {
  \exp_after:wN \__lbj_curr_size_aux:NNw #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__lbj_curr_size:N { c }

\cs_new:Npn \__lbj_curr_size_aux:NNw #1 #2 #3 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 }
   {
    \__lbj_curr_size:N #2
   }
   {
    \cs_to_str:N #2
   }
 }

% just print the current size name
\NewDocumentCommand{\currentsizename}{}
 {
  \lbj_curr_size:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definesizecommand}{mmmO{}}
 {% #1 is the command to define,
  % #2 is the argument specifier,
  % #3 is the list of actions,
  % #4 is the optional action to do in uncovered cases
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{#2}
   {
    \str_case:fnF
     { \lbj_curr_size: }
     { #3 }
     { #4 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definesizecommand{\foo}{}{
  {normalsize}{normalfoo}
  {small}{smallfoo}
  {tiny}{tinyfoo}
}[extrafoo]

\definesizecommand{\baz}{m}{
  {normalsize}{---#1---}
  {small}{!#1!}
  {tiny}{?#1?}
}[(#1)]

\begin{document}

Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{x}

\small
Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{y}

\tiny
Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{z}

\Large
Here we're in \currentsizename: \foo\ and \baz{A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just spectacular (!) Actually, that is what I was trying to implement. Therefore you broke the "tie" between Ulrike and Christian with this complete solution. Wow! The other solutions are more didactical, easy to understand but yours is top. Thanks for taking so much time. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd just query `\@currsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\queryfont[3]{%
  \ifx\@currsize#1
    #2%
  \else
    #3%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\queryfont\small{This is small}{This is not small}

\small
\queryfont\small{This is small}{This is not small}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Amazingly elegant! :-o I prefer Ulrike-Christian's answer because it directly answers my problem with the expansion.

Answer (score 4):

`{\small \f@size}` is not a number. You should better store the f@size-value first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\f@size=9}{the size is 9}{the size is not 9}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\small
\ifthenelse{\f@size=9}{the size is 9}{the size is not 9}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
{\small \xdef\smallfsize{\f@size}}
\ifthenelse{\f@size=\smallfsize}{the size is small}{the size is not small}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot! I knew the answer had to do with some kind of expansion at the definition. By the way @Christian Hupfer. You answered almost simultaneously. Sorry I can only choose one answer :)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: Actually, I was faster ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I've stored the font size `\f@size` of `\small` first (before `\begin{document}` and use `\ifthenelse{...}` to compare this with the current size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
{\small\xdef\smallfontsize{\f@size}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\large

\ifthenelse{\f@size = \smallfontsize }{the size is small}{the size is not small}

\small

\ifthenelse{\f@size = \smallfontsize }{the size is small}{the size is not small}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]