# Changing command definition depending on the font size / location

Tags: fontsize, ifthenelse

Currently I define my multiplication with

```
\newcommand{\m}{ \!\cdot\!}}
```

but I would like to have the `\!` only there if the font is large enough. How do I check for the size of the font?

The important point here is, that the `\m` might be  - for example - in a subscript (e.g. of an integral) and there I do not want to have `\!`.

I tried

```
\makeatletter
{\small \xdef\normalfontsize{\f@size}}
\newcommand{\m}{ \ifthenelse{\f@size<\normalfontsize} \cdot \ifthenelse{\f@size<\normalfontsize}{}{\!}  }
\makeatother
```

inspired from [Identifying and writing the font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291327/identifying-and-writing-the-font-size/291343#291343), but this did not work - I always get the `\!`.

Comment: You could define `\m` with a `\mathchoice`, like `\newcommand{\m}{\mathchoice{\!\cdot\!}{\!\cdot\!}{\cdot}{\cdot}}`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148774/134574).

Comment: As far as I know, in subscripts and exponents, you should use a simple \ cdot, as the spacing is adapted.